# PHP call function from another function inside class

Tags: php

Im am trying to make a class, that will handle every action to the database.

My class:

```
class DBHandler {

    public function connect() {
      echo "<script>alert('connect')</script>"; // cant get here
    }

    public function login($username, $password) {

      // echo "<script>alert('login')</script>";

      $this->connect();
    }
}
```

I would like to call the `connect()` function from the `login()` function, but for some reason, I can't call the `connect()` function.

I thought I could achieve this with `$this->myFunction();`

When I test the code, it just gives me a white screen.

What am I doing horribly wrong? It looks fine to me.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I don't have any access to error log files on the server

Comment: [There's nothing wrong with the class](https://3v4l.org/VdavQ). How are you testing it?

Comment: Try add return with $this->connect(); like return $this->connect();

Comment: I kind of missed the instance